# Notification for a terminal emulator window client-server chat in C

Tags: c, notifications, console, focus

I want to find a way to know when a terminal emulator window has the focus in Linux. So when the client receives a message, if it doesn't have the focus I can display a notification like this:

```
if(!have_focus()){
    display_notification();
}
```

How can I achieve this in C?

Comment: You need to get your terminology straight: the thing Linux calls a "console" is probably not what you are thinking of, and in particular the concept of "focus" does not apply to it.  I am guessing that you actually mean "terminal emulator window", in which case the answer is "a program running in a pseudoterminal has no access to this information, you are going to need to rewrite this chat application as an X client" but I suspect you don't know a number of the words I just used and you will need to research them before you even know how to begin...

Comment: Oh, also, depending on which windowing environment is in use, there may not _be_ any way to "display a notification".  Some GUI designers don't believe notifications should even be possible.  Yes, really.

Comment: Yes I was meaning the "terminal emulator window". I will read about "X client application". I don't care if the notifications doesn't work on all  platform, it is working on the system I target and that is enough for me.

Comment: For what I understand, an X application is like a graphic application and that not what I want to have. Also can you explain me what is the difference between what I called console and "terminal emulator window"

Comment: I cannot fit an explanation into the comment box.  Go to the library and get yourself a copy of _Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment_ by W. Richard Stevens and read it cover to cover.  That will get you started.